# Sort array adapter after item add

Tags: android, sorting, adapter

how can I force array adapter to sort itself. notifyDataSetChanged doesn't work. What I want to do is to add an item to array adpater and then force it to sort again.
This is my adpater:

```
    this.noteListViewAdapter = new NoteListViewAdapter(this.GetActivityContext(), R.layout.list_view_note_item, noteItems);

    // sorting
    this.noteListViewAdapter.sort(new Comparator<NoteItem>()
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(NoteItem item1, NoteItem item2)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return item2.CreationDate.compareTo(item1.CreationDate);
        };
    });
```

It works fine. Items are sorted. But then when I want to add new item, sorting doesn't work. Its not even called.
This is how I add new item:

```
    this.noteListViewAdapter.add(note);
    this.noteListViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: sort it again after add() before notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to call `sort()` inside your `add()` method after adding the passed `note` to the internal list of `noteItems`.

Or you could call that inside `notifyDataSetChanged()` before calling `super.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

I think the latter is even better, as this way you don't sort every time when batch-`add()`ing items.

Answer (score 0):

Don't call sort() inside notifyDataSetChanged() or you will get, guess what, a StackOverFlow ! :)

sort() already calls notifyDataSetChanged()